# Simple OpenGL texture map not working?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to figure out texture mapping in OpenGL and I can't get a simple example to work.

The polygon is being drawn, though it's not textured but just a solid color. Also the bitmap is being loaded correctly into sprite1[] as I was successfully using glDrawPixels up til now.

I use glGenTextures to get my tex name, but I notice it doesn't change texName1; this GLuint is whatever I initialize it to, even after the call to glGenTextures...

I have enabled GL_TEXTURE_2D.

Heres the code:

```
GLuint texName1 = 0;

glGenTextures(1, &texName1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName1);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, sprite1[18], sprite1[22], 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &sprite1[54]);

glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 0.0, -5.0f);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (.5, 0.0, -5.0f);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (.5, .5, -5.0f);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (0.0, .5, -5.0f);
glEnd();
```

UPDATE:
I'm at a loss. Here's everything I've tried:

1. Turns out I was initializing my texture before OGL was initialized. The texture is initialized (glGenTextures->glTexImage2D) in a class constructor and drawn (glBegin->glEnd) in a member function that is called every frame. genTextures appears to be working correctly now and I'm getting a name of 1.
2. Every possible combination of GL_RGBA8, GL_BGRA_EXT (GL_BGRA doesn't work on my system; I need the _EXT), and I even removed the alpha channel from the bitmap and tried all combinations of GL_RGB, GL_BGR_EXT, etc etc. No luck.
3. Tried procedurally creating a bitmap and using that
4. Made sure GL_COLOR_MATERIAL isn't enabled.
5. Changed bitmap size to 32x32.
6. Tried glTexEnvi instead of glTexEnvf.

Comment: if texName1 is remaining 0 after glGenTextures you should check your error conditions...

Comment: Is the width & height stored as byte or int in sprite1[]?

Comment: width and height is stored as byte little endian. I've used sprite1[18] and sprite1[22] successfully before with glDrawPixels; they are correct. The bitmap is only 29x20 pixels so it works.

Comment: Also, how do I check error conditions? From the reference pages I don't see that glGenTextures generates any errors that would be useful to me using glGetError().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My call to `glEnable` was `glEnable(GL_BLEND | GL_TEXTURE_2D)`. Using glGetError I saw I was getting a GL_INVALID_ENUM for this call, so I moved GL_TEXTURE_2D to its own enable function and bingo. I guess logical OR isn't allowed for glEnable?

Comment: AFAIK OpenGL constants aren't just powers of two, they're arbitrary values. Which would mean that using logical OR would destroy information.

Comment: The OR-able constants are these with -BIT in the name, like GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT. Not a lot of them in GL, so don't get used to it.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [mentat's note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742342/simple-opengl-texture-map-not-working/759322#759322) that you might have a problem with non-power-of-two texture dimensions, you mention the texture name generation not changing the name.

That sounds as if you're calling `glGenTextures()` too early, i.e. before initializing OpenGL. If you're not, then I suggest adding code just after the call to `glGenTextures()` that check the OpenGL error state, by calling `glGetError()`.

Comment: This worked for me...I was trying to create textures before OpenGL initialization.  As I have seen time and time again: order of function calls are so important in OpenGL programming.

Answer (score 4):

In your comments, you say your bitmap is 29x20 pixels. Afaik to generate a valid texture, OpenGL requires that the image size (on each dimension) be a power of 2. It doesn't need to be a square, it can be a rectangle though. You can overcome this by using some OpenGL extensions like [GL_ARB_texture_rectangle](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_rectangle.txt).

Comment: GL_ARB_texture_rectangle has been incorporated into OpenGL since 2.0, http://www.opengl.org/wiki/NPOT_Texture

Answer (score 2):

I'll put this here as I had the same issue and found another post explaining the issue.
The iPhone does support GL_BGRA(GL_EXT_BGRA) but seemingly only as an input format and not as an internal format. So, if you change the glTexImage2D call to have an internal format of GL_RGBA then it works.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &sprite1[54]);
```

I hope this helps someone else that stumbles upon this post.

Comment: I'd love to hear more on this, as it's been confusing me. It seems putting BGRA as an internal format works, but it is actually using RGBA. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

Some random ideas:

- GL_COLOR_MATERIAL might be enabled
- change "glTexEnvf" to "glTexEnvi" and see if that helps
- if texName1 is 0 after glGenTextures you might not have an active OpenGL context

For error checking I recommend writing a small function that prints readable output for the most common results from glGetErrors and use that to find the line that creates the error. Another possibility would be to use something like [GLIntercept](http://glintercept.nutty.org/), [BuGLe](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/) or [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/).

Answer (score 1):

My OpenGL is rusty, but I remember having same problems with with `glTexImage2D`
. Finally I managed to make it work, but I always had more luck with    `gluBuild2DMipmaps`
so i ended up with

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps (
  GL_TEXTURE_2D, type, i.width, i.height, type, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, i.data
);
```

which replaced

```
glTexImage2D (
  GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, type, i.width, i.height, 0, type, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, i.data 
);
```

Comment: That sounds like a forgotten glTexParameter for the MIN filter. The default would be GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR which would only work with mipmapped textures.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd check is the colour material setting, as mentioned by ShadowIce, then check your texture file to ensure it's a reasonable size (i.e. something like 256x256) and an RGB bitmap. If the file has even a slight problem it WILL NOT render correctly, no matter how you try.

Then, I'd stop trying to just debug that code and instead see what you have different to the [tutorial on the NeHe website](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06).

NeHe is always a good place to check if you're trying to do stuff in OpenGL. Textures are probably the hardest thing to get right, and they only get more difficult as the rest of your GL skills increase.