# OpenGL texture mapping stubbornly refuses to work

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdl, d, texture-mapping

I'm writing a 2D game using SDL and OpenGL in the D programming language. At the moment it simply tries to render a texture-mapped quad to the screen. Problem is, the whole texture-mapping part doesn't quite seem to work. Despite the texture apparently loading fine (gets assigned a nonzero texture number, doesn't cause glGetError to return values other than zero), the quad is rendered with the last color set in glColor, entirely ignoring the texture.

I've looked for common reasons for texture mapping to fail, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742342/simple-opengl-texture-map-not-working), to no avail. The image file being loaded is 64x64, a valid power-of-2 size.

Please don't get scared off because this is in D—it's almost entirely C-style SDL and OpenGL calls.

SDL initialization code:

```
if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1) == -1 ||
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0) == -1)
    throw new Exception("An OpenGL attribute could not be set!");

uint videoFlags = SDL_OPENGL | SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_ANYFORMAT;

if (threadsPerCPU() > 1)
    videoFlags |= SDL_ASYNCBLIT;

SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, videoFlags);

if (screen == null)
    throw new Exception("SDL_SetVideoMode failed!");
```

OpenGL initialization code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0., 800, 600, 0., 0., 1.);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
```

Texture loading code:

```
SDL_Surface* s = IMG_Load(toStringz("hello.png"));

if (s == null)
    throw new Exception("Image file could not be loaded!");

uint texFormat;

switch (s.format.BytesPerPixel)
{
case 4:
    texFormat = (s.format.Rmask == 0x000000ff ? GL_RGBA : GL_BGRA);
    break;
case 3:
    texFormat = (s.format.Rmask == 0x000000ff ? GL_RGB : GL_BGR);
    break;
default:
    throw new Exception("Bad pixel format!");
    break;
}

if ((s.w & (s.w - 1)) != 0)
    throw new Exception("Width must be a power of 2!");
if ((s.h & (s.h - 1)) != 0)
    throw new Exception("Height must be a power of 2!");

uint glName;

glGenTextures(1, &glName);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glName);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, s.format.BytesPerPixel, s.w, s.h, 0,
    texFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, s.pixels);

SDL_FreeSurface(s);
```

Rendering code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glName);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(64, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(64, 64);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, 64);
glEnd();

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
```

My program uses Derelict2, a library that provides SDL and OpenGL bindings for D.

Any ideas on exactly what is going awry here?

Edit: For future reference, here's the solution to my problem:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture

I needed to set a couple parameters prior to calling `glTexImage2D` or else my texture was technically incomplete. Adding the following four lines just before that call did the trick:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter of glTexImage, "format" IS NOT bytes per pixel. Historically the values 1, 2, 3, 4 were accepted by OpenGL-1.0. Since OpenGL-1.1 and onwards the format parameter only accepts well defined tokens, like GL_RGBA, GL_RGB, etc. which numeric value has not relation to the actual format.

Comment: Please forget about the concept of "OpenGL initialization". Yes, you load textures and stuff, but in any real world application this is not a one time thing, but happens on demand. All the rendering state, i.e. projection, clear color, viewport, etc. should be set right before they're needed in the rendering procedure. All the stuff you've placed in the "OpenGL initialization code" section belongs to the start of the "Rendering code" section.

Comment: @datenwolf: Points taken. Regarding your first comment, the docs I was using must have been outdated, so I'll update the call to use one of the OpenGL enum values instead. Regarding the second comment, I think it's appropriate in my particular app to lump things like the projection, viewport, etc. into the init code, but only because my particular app only ever uses one perspective of the scene (just a static 2D view so I can do hardware-accelerated 2D drawing). I definitely see your point though.

Comment: Perhaps I will split out those portions of the so-called "init" code into a separate function for added clarity, and also since I now realize that resizing of the video output will likely require changing the viewport after init time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One common mistake is to create/use an incomplete texture, see [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture).

Your code does not show any call to :

```
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR/*or GL_NEAREST*/);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR/*or GL_NEAREST*/);
```

and also does not show any mipmap creation.

You problem may be related to your texture being incomplete.

Comment: Wow, you are completely right. After adding the four lines listed at the linked page, the texture now renders completely as intended. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: I wonder why glGetError didn't indicate anything after the glTexImage2D; perhaps its available error codes just don't cover this sort of thing. In any case, at least I have something working now so I can worry about mipmaps or other modifications later.

Comment: hm, glTexImage2D can't indicate/detect the error, as its used to construct the texture, and during the process, it is 'legal' to an incomplete texture. Perhaps the 'glBindTexture' could detect this as an error, but I'm not sure, as with shaders, if you sample the texture only in mipmap 0, it may work (untested). Once you've been bitten many times by this problem, you get used to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a vague theory here: have you tried drawing the vertices counter-clockwise instead of clockwise?

```
glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, 64);
glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(64, 64);
glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(64, 0);
```

Comment: Just recompiled with the direction change; same deal. :(

Comment: Is there a reason for the glBindTexture call in the texture loading code (at least in the position that it's in)? I would've thought it would go after the glTexImage2D call - it's been a while since I worked with OpenGL though.

Comment: @Xono: To my knowledge, the `glBindTexture` call tells the OpenGL state machine "we're working with this texture now", while the `glTexImage2D` call implicitly understands that it should apply to the currently bound texture. Correct me if I'm wrong, of course.

Comment: Nope you're right in that regard, went and checked NeHe's tutorial on texture mapping (http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06 if you're interested) :P Only other things I can think of to look at: No translation of the poly away from the camera, or the call to glColor4ub overriding the texture data in the vertex definitions (shouldn't be though).

Comment: Yeah, I have seen NeHe's tutorial on this topic (it's partly what I based my code upon). Removing the `glColor` call, in my experience, only makes it harder to tell if the quad drew, because with the call as it is, I'm guaranteed to get a white square, so it's very easy to tell that the quad drew but the texture mapping itself didn't happen.

Comment: What exactly is appearing, is the white quad taking the whole screen or is it only using part of it? If you change the color in the glColor call does it update the color of the quad appropriately (I sincerely hope it does)? Also, does anywhere in your code set the modelview matrix to identity?

Comment: The white quad is taking up the 64x64 region of the screen that it should. Calling `glColor` with another color does indeed change the quad's color. And no, I don't set the modelview matrix to identity at any point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a `glOrtho(0., 800, 600, 0., 0., 1.);` in the paintGL function?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't it, because I definitely get an on-screen white square. A glOrtho problem would be a problem with the position/orientation of the scene, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`? I haven't used the fixed-functionality pipeline in a while, but I think that might do it.

Comment: I added `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)` to my init code, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to help.